# Why I cannot assign OnKey Alt+V and Alt+H in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign a shortcut key for my macro. However, I cannot use Alt+V or Alt+H to call my procedure. Is there anything that linked with the system default shortcut key? Because I can use Ctrl+V in my OnKey and it works fine.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.OnKey "%{V}", "testing"
Application.OnKey "%{H}", "testing2"
End Sub
```

I really need to use both of these shortcut keys since other combinations have been used.
Thank you.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that Alt is the shortcut to activate Ribbon commands (and old keyboard shortcut sequences from 2003 and earlier)

Comment: First it would be `Application.OnKey "%V", "testing"` and second Rory is right and the ALT shortcuts are tied to the ribbon for example alt+h is opening the help ribbon.

Comment: So there is no way to override it?

Comment: 1. Looks like no. 2. If it would be possible every Excel user using your sheet will hate you for overriding standard shortcuts.